# attach image to facebook log in button in messenger

Tags: node.js, facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I'm new to facebook messenger bots. I would like to send a login button with an image, but i can't figure out how.

```
if (received_message.text) {    
    response = {
      "attachment":{
        "type":"template",
        "payload":{
          "template_type":"button",
          "text":"my_text",
          "buttons":[
            {
              "type": "account_link",
              "url": "my_link.com/login"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I know there's an image_url property, but I don't know where to place it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Attach the login button to a generic template:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic